# Meteor log clientside errors on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, logging

Hello in my Meteor application i want to log my errors, that happen on the clientside, on the server log.

The logger i use is: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-logger

And there's this sample code:

```
 /* Store original window.onerror */
const _GlobalErrorHandler = window.onerror;

window.onerror = (msg, url, line) => {
  log.error(msg, {file: url, onLine: line});
  if (_GlobalErrorHandler) {
    _GlobalErrorHandler.apply(this, arguments);
  }
};
```

Where is the variable `log`coming from?

I tried to import my logger from server but it seems like it didn't work..
I don't get an exception but there's nothing written in the log.

Note: The logger is working on the serverside

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the usage of your package, you should be defining `log` by calling `const log = new Logger()`. Then registering adaptors (explained on the github page you linked) to do something with the messages you are logging.

This can be done simply using [this adaptor](https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/loggerconsole). After installing, add the following code above what you already have:

```
const log = new Logger();
new LoggerConsole(log).enable();
```

As described in the loggerconsole docs this will automatically: "Print Client's log messages to Server's console package".

The code you have provided simply listens for the errors.